# Sending commands to application via socket server

Tags: android

What is the best way to implement a handler for serving commands that come over a socket, all of this is done over a LAN and never over 3g or anywhere outside my home network.

For example

```
1- App Starts
   -Sends Hello I am at IP x.x.x.x to a computer on the local network
   -Person at computer now has a terminal open where he can input various 
    pre-defined strings such as "vibrate" "call number" "text number" etc
```

I've already programmed the first part, where as soon as the main activity is called it sends it's IP Address over a socket and i've also created the interface for connecting to the server ran on the phone.

The thing I need help in implementing is, how do I set up a server on the phone which can
handle multiple strings (instead of just terminating the stream after one string is recieved), and what method is the best for mapping different strings to functions

Comment: Did you try and Google it? Seems something like this would do: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: I am trying that, but i want to run it as a service and it wont let me use the classes you defind outside of the onCreate() functions within the onCreate function

Comment: Nevermind, i forgot to add a 'new' before starting an instance of the class :(